# Instagram synced many images from a tag with Real time, what to do with deleted images

Tags: instagram

Using the <kbd>[Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)</kbd>, I subscribed to a tag with the Real time feature. I sync media that match my project's criteria, then save those to DB. When users visit my website, I display these images from my DB (and not from instagram API).

From time to time, I see broken links showing up in the images. I identified that the source of the problem is that those images have now been deleted.

What's a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not attempting to duplicate the Instagram DB (or part thereof) would be the best option. Depending on the usage of your project and what sort of tags you're subscribing to, that could get pretty large pretty quickly.

Short of that, doing a quick HTTPRequest to the image URL (and checking the response code) before deciding whether to display it would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve Crawford is on the right track.

The problem with your solution is that you are duplicating volatile data that you:

a) can't control

b) don't receive notifications on.

I would think the better method would be track the meta data of the images you are interested (like the author, url,date,etc) and then display them if they are still available.

If you are going to cache data you also need to a way to invalidate your cache. So another option would be to duplicate the data as you already are, but also have a background job to ensure that the data is still valid and remove the ones that aren't.